# $_POST doesn't contain all data

Tags: php, post

Since a few days ago, we've a problem in an online shop. (Gambio bases on xtC)

We have a formula with more than 3000 text fields. About the first third of them work correctly; the rest is null, empty.

It seems that $_POST is filled correctly, but on the server, the app gets a reduced array.

I tested it on different computers, with different browsers, with different content: => always the same.

```
Server: Linux infong 2.4 #1 SMP Mon Oct 10 09:34:36 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

PHP Version 5.2.17 (build 12-29-2011)

`post_max_size` is 8 MB.

The problems were recognized on 12-30-2011, so it might be connected with the new build on the server.

Has somebody ideas concerning this problem?

Comment: 3000 text fields? I feel bad for whoever has to fill those out... :s

Comment: Are you sure it's completely filled? You can check that with TamperData (Firefox Addon). What does print_r($_POST) say? Any changes in your 4th text field and what's the value / content of it?

Comment: Do you have Suhosin patch installed? It can limit the number of keys that $_POST can contain.

Comment: Was the `post_max_size` changed from before?

Comment: `post_max_size` and maybe also `memory_limit` could be a point to check.

Comment: **Warning** as of PHP 5.4 the default limit on input fields is 1000. Same for the suhosin patch, which also limits the amount of input fields. You already mentioned that there's approx. 1/3 of 3000, which is 1000.

Comment: Have you tried with a single test script? See [Andy Hassall](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/11712-_post-limit) post sample.

Comment: Check your value of `ini_get('suhosin.post.max_vars'))` as @N.B. suggested.

Comment: @Svish be shure, there is nobody who will be forced to fill them all.

Comment: @SnOopy thanks, I will try TamperData

Comment: @hakre we don't know. We hope to be informed by the management of the server.
It is a part of a webhosting-packet.

Comment: @BloodyWorld memory-limit? I can't get the information with phpinfo-php.
I just got: '--enable-memory-limit'
Do You know, where and how I can get this information?

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt   Thanks for this useful information

Comment: @Peter: Try to find out what happens if a post request has more data than allowed by PHP. Check if it's truncated or completely dropped. If it's completely dropped, than the post_max_size is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: @hakre i tested it already. Only data beyond a special point is dropped.

Comment: @Peter: Talk to the server guys they raise the php_max_size limit, e.g. to 16MB.

Comment: It’s `$_POST` (*sic!*) and not `$POST` or `$post`.

Comment: INFORMATION: Thanks for the info about Tamper Data. Great.

Comment: INFORMATION: all data until the end is in http-data.

Comment: INFORMATION: all data together is about 400 kB.

Comment: INFORMATION: i just checked it: It must be a new limit. 1000 fields are ok, all above is dropped.

Comment: Problem identified :-) ------ NOT solved :-(

Comment: Evaluate it against raw post data from `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Answer (score 1):

> The problems were recognized on 12-30-2011, so it might be connected with the new build on the server.

If you're using a PHP version provided by your linux distribution, it's very likely that they backported [this patch to PHP 5.3 and 5.4](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=321040), designed to mitigate a [possible attack vector](http://cryptanalysis.eu/blog/2011/12/28/effective-dos-attacks-against-web-application-plattforms-hashdos/) that impacts PHP and numerous other languages and libraries.

If this is the case, try dumping a `phpinfo()` and look for `max_input_vars`.  If it's there, you can set it in php.ini to a higher number, as you see fit.  If you don't see it, it's likely that you didn't receive that exact patch and the number has been hard-coded by your distribution.